# Finding maximum and minimum values from a Bash array

Tags: bash, shell

I have a *.txt* file that has integer values written in it with a ";" separator.

117;92;16;20;

I need to compare these and select the highest one.

My code:

```
IFS=';' #Internat Field Separator
read -ra vector<$file
max=$vector[0]
min=$vector[0]

for i in ${vector[@]}
do

if [[ $i > $max ]] ; then
max=$i
fi

if [[ $i < $min ]] ; then
min=$i

fi
done
echo "Max value is $max, minimal value is $min"
break
```

The output is:

> Max value is 92, minimal value is 16.

So of course this is wrong. When I try to echo it:

```
echo $value ( in a loop of course )
```

The output is

> 177[0] 92 16 25

Why does the first letter show as int[0]? Because of that I cannot compare them. I can't figure out anything...

Comment: `max=${vector[0]}; min=${vector[0]}`

Comment: If you'd checked whether it was the reading-to-an-array-from-a-file that was actually your problem before asking, you could have asked a much more focused question.

Comment: `declare -p vector`, by the way, is a best-practices way to print a fully known/knowable value for the variable by that name.

Comment: Hate using bash for such purposes. `python -c "import sys; print(max(int(i) for i in sys.stdin.readline().split(';')))" <yourfile`

Comment: @OlegAndriyanov, eh? bash is fine for the purpose, though the OP is using it exceedingly badly (for instance, they're performing ASCII string comparison, not numeric comparison). Still, the overhead of starting the Python interpreter overwhelms the shell's execution time for any reasonable list length.

Comment: @sadboy, ...btw, consider running code through http://shellcheck.net/ in the future before asking questions here.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I know this site but it won't show any errors this time, that's why i bothered to ask here.

Comment: @sadboy, ...it didn't show any errors *directly relating to the bug at hand*, but there certainly were errors; it was thus evident that it hadn't been consulted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your trailing `[0]`s are caused by failing to use curly brackets in your parameter expansions. There's no need for them beyond clarity, anyhow -- referring to `$vector` expands the first element if `vector` is an array.

The largest issue here is that `[[ $foo > $bar ]]` compares these values **as strings**, not as numbers, hence `92` being larger than `166` (since it starts with `9` rather than `1`). Use `(( ))` to enter a math context, in which `<` and `>` perform numeric comparisons and `$` sigils are unnecessary surrounding variable names.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

IFS=';' read -ra vector <"$file"
max=${vector[0]}
min=${vector[0]}

for i in "${vector[@]}"; do
  (( i > max )) && max=$i
  (( i < min )) && min=$i
done

echo "Max value is $max, minimal value is $min"
```